# Prevent Microsoft Office from auto starting on Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, osx-mavericks, autostart

Whenever I start up my Mac Mini (running OS Mavericks) or Macbook Air (OS 10.9), I have to wait while Word and Excel automatically load and open.
I've tried stopping this from happening via system preferences, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check...

- That it doesn't have entries in System Prefs/Users & Groups [your account] then right hand pane, Login Items, making them auto-launch.
- That both are in fact Quit, not just that all their windows are closed, before you shut down or restart.

If both of these are OK, then...

- Switch to Finder.
  Open a new window  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>   then Go to Folder…  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd> 
  Copy/paste this `~/Library/Saved Application State` [including the tilde ~] & hit  <kbd>Enter ⌅</kbd>  .
  Look for folders called `com.microsoft.Excel.savedState` & `com.microsoft.Word.savedState` & delete them.